# How to verify installation of ImageMagick is not vulnerable to CVE-2016-3714

Tags: security, imagemagick

[CVE-2016-3714](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-3714) was announced on May 3, 2016. This vulnerability unfortunately goes by the name, [ImageTragick](https://imagetragick.com/) and has received some press (for example, [this ArsTechnica article](http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/05/easily-exploited-bug-exposes-huge-number-of-sites-to-code-execution-attacks/)).

Until updated ImageMagick packages are released in the near future, we need a workaround. The workaround is fairly straight-forward. Simply use a policy file to disable the vulnerable coders. The policy file must look something like this:

```
<policymap>
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPHEMERAL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="URL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MVG" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MSL" />
</policymap>
```

If a sysadmin has installed the policy.xml file shown above, how would they go about independently confirming that the installation of ImageMagick is no longer vulnerable?

Comment: It was not clear if I should ask here or on http://security.stackexchange.com/, but I believe this falls more into the realm of system administration than information security. I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Karim Valiev [posted information](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2016/05/03/18) to the oss-security mailing list, showing how to check the local install of ImageMagick to see if it is vulnerable.

Create a file called exploit.mvg with the following contents:

```
push graphic-context
viewbox 0 0 640 480
fill 'url(https://example.com/image.jpg"|ls "-la)'
pop graphic-context
```

Then run the convert utility:

```
$ convert exploit.mvg out.png
```

If you see a local directory listing, your installation of ImageMagick is **not** sufficiently protected.